# Alternative solutions to using a dynamic DNS service to manage a failover ethernet/cellular device

Tags: ip, failover

We have RS232 sensors connected to a serial device server that manages both ethernet(primary)WAN and cellular(failover)WWAN connectivity. A database application requires a single IP to manage each sensor. Currently, I'm manually switching the IPs when WAN is down (~twice per month). I'm aware of dynamic DNS services that can manage the 2 IPs and resolve into a single name, but this is not allowed in our situation.

I'm looking for alternative solutions to dynamic DNS.

- Both the Ethernet and cellular IPs are static
- Ethernet is on a private WAN with the database server and cellular is publicly accessable

Comment: Unfortunately, protocols above OSI layer-4 (e.g. DNS) are explicitly off-topic here. It also sounds like the WAN failover happens correctly, but the problem is with your application, and that is off-topic, too. You should try to ask this question on [so] from a programming perspective, or on [sf] from a network perspective.

Comment: Why isn't dynamic DNS allowed?  Can you host your own dynamic DNS?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking (by which I mean, I'm not interested in spending enough time)... but this is "ip config" so it seems there might be an on-topic part/aspect of this... let's see if the community responds..

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional managed networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they function rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Things like hosting your own dynamic DNS is not a network question, rather a server/service/application question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DNS implementation, you could accomplish this with ["round-robin" DNS](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/rr.html).  In its basic form, this will return a list of both IPs (your WAN private IP and the WWAN public IP if I'm reading your question correctly) to your database.  The caveat is that DNS cannot guarantee that the client (the database and/or application) will respect the change due to TTLs and/or order of the list of IPs returned in the response.  As the linked article specifies, you can control this to a certain degree with lower TTLs, "split horizon", or SRV records, but that is dependent upon your DNS, as well as your application and database support of those features. So I concur that your question is better suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as [Ron Maupin](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8499/ron-maupin) pointed out. There are much better ways to handle this type of situation at the application level, e.g. service discovery a la [Consul](https://www.consul.io/).